# Joomla new version URL not possible with subdirectory?

Tags: url, joomla, subdirectory, slash

In my old version of joomla I used "menu-link" and named the subdirectory /xxx/
All the URLs are on that subdirectory also google knows that.
so :

```
/xxx/jantje
/xxx/pietje
/xxx/enverder
etc.
```

Now... a new version of Joomla (only "menu-alias" available) and a new website and it is not possible to place that subdirectory in front of all the menu items ... :(
And I dont want the urls to change.
Joomla makes from `/xxx/` a name with a dash  --> `xxx-` 
so :

```
xxx-jantje
xxx-pietje
xxx-enverder
```

Does anybody know how to solve this? I really like the URLS to stay with the subdirectoryname in it.

Thnks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by :

comment-out the line 95 from:  `./libraries/joomla/filter/output.php`

```
//$str = trim(JString::strtolower($str));
```

and change to:

```
$str = trim($str);
```

comment-out the line 370 from: ./libraries/joomla/filter/language.php

```
//$string = JString::strtolower($string));
```

Now you can use in the alias also characters like `/`.